# delete overlapping points

Tags: arcgis-desktop, point, overlapping-features

I have two different files. One data represents points in green, another - points in red. I want to select points in red, but only those, which has no intersection with green points. What solution will you offer? I am using ArcGIS software.
The picture illustrates data and wanted result.
[image]

Comment: What GIS software are you using?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  I recommend not thinking about GIS SE as being some sort of online GIS tutor.  For your questions to be answered here they should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.

Comment: Thanks you for explanation. So I was stuck to find right geoprocessing function, which is opposite to "intersection". I finally, I found that there is "erase" function, which fits for me.

Answer (score 1):

- Merge all Points into merged.shp
- Intersect merged into intersecting.shp
- Select By Location from merged.shp where Intersect intersecting.shp
- Open the Attribute Table of merged.shp, reverse the Select
  Set